# How to find the the word position (not character position) in a string

Tags: string, vba

Suppose i have a string separated by spaces/hyphens.

Eg. Take these broken wings and learn to fly.

What vba function can find the position of the word broken which should be returned as 3, not 11 which is the character position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (there probably is a more efficient way) would be to split the string and iterate over the returned array:

```
Function wordPosition(sentence As String, searchWord As String) As Long

    Dim words As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    words = Split(sentence, " ")
    For i = LBound(words, 1) To UBound(words, 1)
        If words(i) = searchWord Then Exit For
    Next i

    'return -1 if not found
    wordPosition = IIf(i > UBound(words, 1), -1, i + 1)

End Function
```

You can call it ilke this:

```
Sub AnExample()

    Dim s As String
    Dim sought As String

    s = "Take these broken wings and learn to fly"
    sought = "broken"

    MsgBox sought & " is in position " & wordPosition(s, sought)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. The function works fine, but in case there are multiple instances of the word in the string, the function will not be able to detect the respective positions.

Comment: You could `if strcomp(left$(words(i), len(searchword)), searchword, vbtextcompare) = 0 then exit for` which would make `"broken"` also match `"BRoken?  "`

Comment: @AlexK. I am not completely sure about what you mean. Also bear in mind that you can get the same result that you propose by relying on LCase. The OP is not saying that he expects "broken" being equal to "BRoken", but finding all the existing "broken" in a given string (which might be more than one); I guess that the only approach to deliver this (with this function), is storing all the occurences in an array and returning it (instead of a single position), what delivers the code in my answer (which is just an updated version of this code).

Comment: The `?` in the comment was to indicate the effect of ignoring punctuation chars

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by assylias is pretty good and just need a small adaptation to account for multiple occurrences:

```
Function wordPosition(sentence As String, searchWord As String) As Long()

    Dim words As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    words = Split(sentence, " ")
    Dim matchesCount As Long: matchesCount = 0
    ReDim matchesArray(UBound(words) + 1) As Long
    For i = LBound(words, 1) To UBound(words, 1)
        If words(i) = searchWord Then
           matchesCount = matchesCount + 1
           matchesArray(matchesCount) = IIf(i > UBound(words, 1), -1, i + 1)
        End If
    Next i

    If (matchesCount > 0) Then
       matchesArray(0) = matchesCount
    End If

    wordPosition = matchesArray

End Function


Sub AnExample()

    Dim s As String
    Dim sought As String

    s = "Take these broken wings and learn to fly and broken again"
    sought = "broken"

    Dim matches() As Long: matches = wordPosition(s, sought)

    If (matches(0) > 0) Then
       Dim count As Integer: count = 0
       Do
          count = count + 1
          MsgBox "Match No. " & count & " for " & sought & " is in position " & matches(count)
       Loop While (count < matches(0))

    End If

End Sub
```